# In memory OLAP engine in Java

Tags: java, olap

Is there an in memory OLAP (slice and dice data) Java library.
(The equivalent of Microsoft Analytic Services).
Especially would like to hear if anyone has used one for real.

Comment: You should tag this with "data mining" and also include that in your searches for a library.

Comment: No, you should not tag this with data mining. ;-) because it does not involve some kind of statistical analysis. OLAP is data cube queries, and you can use it for various stuff, but it's not the kind of complex statistic that data mining is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java Data Mining ([JDM 2.0](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=247)) is a standard Java API for developing data mining applications and tools.

Comment: Java Data Mining (JDM) is **nonexistant** and **dead**. There is Weka and Rapidminer and ELKI and KNIME. But JDM is dead.

Answer (score 7):

[www.icCube.com](http://www.icCube.com) is a JAVA in-memory OLAP server. It can be either embedded in your application or you can access it via our XMLA client library or any other XMLA JAVA client library. Note that the engine itself is quite light. Yes, it is used in production.

Comment: If this is your product your should give a disclaimer to that effect.

Answer (score 6):

you can also read more about ActivePivot from [here](http://www.quartetfs.com/activepivot+real-time+incremental+object+olap.php) It is used by many banks to aggregate large amount of data in memory.

Answer (score 3):

Palo & Jedox are great tools. They provide API's for Java (JPalo)
It uses in-memory OLAP cubes, great performance boost.
There are also ETL & Modelling clients written in Java

Check out:

1. http://www.palo.net/
2. http://www.jpalo.com/en/

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a commercial solution, ActivePivot provides what you have asked for: http://quartetfs.com/en/products/activepivot

Answer (score 2):

You also have a French open source in-memory OLAP solution based on J2EE architecture: [Ellipsys Mosaïc](http://www.openserv.fr). But only in French for now...

Answer (score 0):

Another commercial product is Citra Pivot. It can read from in-memory tabular data, and also interfaces with OLAP Server that use the XML/A specification. Results are visualized in a Java/Swing pivot table.

[Citra Pivot](http://www.citra-tech.com/products/pivot.html)